# What is the current authentication protocol for CRM 4.0 on-premise?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, dynamics-crm

The infrastructure team wants to update the authentication protocol to NTLMv2 and Kerberos.  Will this affect CRM 4.0 on-premise installation.  What would need to be changed in order to use the updated protocols.  I am having a difficulty locating any official documentation on what the current authentication protocols are for CRM on-premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will be an issue.  Vista ONLY uses NTLMv2 and CRM runs fine on it.  I can't, however, find any official statement from Microsoft but my assumption is that you'll be fine updating.